# How to read the data from standard output in jatcl by running tcl script in java

Tags: java, tcl, jacl

I have two questions basically. I am using JACL interpreter to run TCL script in JAVA.

My questions are:

1. How to get the data from standard output after running tcl file?
2. How to pass arguments for tcl script when executing using jatcl?

E.G:
sample.tcl:

```
`puts "Hi this is from tcl"  `
```

When ran using java as follows:

```
`Interp i = new Interp();
 i.eval("source sample.tcl");`
```

then the output will be written to stdout console of JAVA. I want to read that output to some variable like `x[] = i.eval("sample.tcl")` then x should contain Hi this is from tcl.

2. How to pass some parameter to `sample.tcl`

Answer (score 1):

Getting standard out is a bit difficult — you have to do a lot of work creating your own instance of a `tcl.lang.channel.Channel` and then plugging that in with `TclIO.registerChannel()`, which isn't really for someone just starting out — yet you often don't need to do that if you are just wanting to communicate with a Tcl program. The result of the script (which is *not* the standard output, but rather the result of the last command in the script) will be available via the `Interp`'s `getResult()` method after the `eval` finishes.

```
Interp interp = new Interp();
interp.eval("source sample.tcl");
String result = interp.getResult().toString();
```

More likely, once you've `source`d the script, you'll then invoke commands in the same interpreter and inspect *their* results. That works much better.

```
Interp interp = new Interp();
interp.eval("source sample.tcl");
String arg = "abc";
interp.eval("sampleCommand " + arg);
String result = interp.getResult().toString();
```

If you want to pass something more complex, the simplest way is to store the value you want to pass in a Tcl variable prior to invoking the script, which can then pull the value out of the variable when it needs it.

```
interp.setVar("theVar", "the value, which may have spaces in it", 0);
interp.eval("sampleCommand $theVar");
```

---

If you're insisting on reading script stdout, you can try this:

```
Interp interp = new Interp();
TclByteArrayChannel tbac = new TclByteArrayChannel(interp);

// WARNING untested, but I think you have to unregister the old stdout first
TclIO.unregisterChannel(interp, TclIO.getStdChannel(StdChannel.STDOUT));
TclIO.registerChannel(interp, tbac);

interp.eval("source sample.tcl");

// The channel will have had *bytes* written to it, so that's what we ought to get
byte[] bytes = TclByteArray.getBytes(interp, tbac.getTclByteArray());
```

I truly do not recommend this. I also wouldn't recommend it if you were interacting with Tcl from any other language either (e.g., C or C++). Tcl is *designed* to integrate at the interpreter-result level that I described earlier; you'll find it much easier to make work for anything complex.

Comment: I tried reading the output from getResult() which is giving me an empty output. I will try reading it from channel and let you know the status

Comment: Hi Donal,
I tried with channel also. It didn't work.
Can you suggest any other frameworks instead of JACL. I need to work run some TCL script and get the output. I need to run using some interpreter?